# Get position of slot item using ISSLOT tag

Tags: intershop

Actually I'm using isslotiterator and I have to use loop in loop to get the position of each slot item with the attribute `counter`.

I would like to know if it is possible to get the position with a `<isslot>`.
Imagine that I have a slot with 3 entries.

So when I'm calling `<isslot>` in the slot item ISML I could do :
#Pagelet:Position#

Then having as result : 1 / 2 / 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No i don't think this is possible. `<isslot>` does not pass the location information down of the pagelet, it just renders it. To have more control of how slot items are rendered, the `isslotiterator` tag was introduced.

You can get the position info from the `SlotPageletAssignment` object if u dont want to use a counter.
Take a look at the Carousel component on the demo homepage.

```
app_sf_responsive_cm/release/templates/default/component/common/Carousel.isml
```

there u can see they use `AssignmentsAlias` key to get the `SlotPageletAssignment`

```
<isslotiterator Slot="#Pagelet:SubSlot("app_sf_responsive_cm:slot.carousel.items.pagelet2-Slot")#" AssignmentsAlias="CarouselPageletAssignments">
<isloop iterator="CarouselPageletAssignments" alias="CarouselPageletAssignment" counter="i">
    #CarouselPageletAssignment:Position# - #CarouselPageletAssignment:getSubPagelet#<br/>
</isloop>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately `position` is not a characteristic of type `Pagelet`. If successfully doing this, you need to work with `PageletAssignment`. So instead of `Pagelet:Position` you need to use `PageletAssignment:Position`.

**BUT**

`isslot` is preparing a render dictionary for your "slot item ISML" that does not contain the assignment that was leading to this "slot item". It only contains the item itself (aka. the pagelet). Reason for that is slots can define a `Pagelet Pipeline` that fully dynamically determine pagelets without the need for assignments.

My suggestion: Either use `isslotiterator` with `AssignmentsAlias` (easy) or use a pagelet pipeline defined at the slotdefinition of your slot (more complicated).

Comment: That pagelet pipeline solution can only be used if pagelets are uniquely assigned to the slot (so no duplicates). Build a pagelet pipeline that receives `Pagelet` and `Slot` (among others) as parameters and use Assignment Framework lookup logic (pipelet GetAssignments). Have a look at pipeline `ProcessPageletAssignments` startnode `GetPageletAssignments` for  example.